# How can I decrypt a password that is in the jboss login-config.xml?

Tags: java, jboss, password-encryption

Is there an API provided by jboss that I can use to access login-config.xml and decrypt the encrypted passwords?

Answer (score 6):

"jaas is the way" is the default key at least for older jboss versions (4.x). you can try something like this to decode the encoded bytes.

```
    public static String decode( String secret ) {
    String retString = "";
    try {
        byte[] kbytes = "jaas is the way".getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec( kbytes, "Blowfish" );

        BigInteger n = new BigInteger( secret, 16 );
        byte[] encoding = n.toByteArray();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "Blowfish" );
        cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key );
        byte[] decode = cipher.doFinal( encoding );
        retString = new String( decode );
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        ignore.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retString;
}
```

Some additional info

https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/resource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java.html

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/jboss/resource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java.html